# Error when try to add map inside fragement TAB

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I am try to add map inside fragment tab. My google map normally works. But when i use map inside tab fragment child then get exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
```

**I want to add map in TAB2**

[image]

> MainActivity.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mTitle.setText("Chili's");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_white).setText("Menu"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_white).setText("Map"));;
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_white).setText("Facebook"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_white).setText("About"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

> activity_maps.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/home_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:name="com.chilis.chilis.Maps" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Map.class

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Maps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myContext.getSupportFragmentManager()      //error
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);  //error

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="--------------">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

</application>
```

Comment: Can you please post the full LogCat error output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that in your `activity_maps.xml` file you are not missing the end tag of LinearLayout: `</ LinearLayout>`.

Comment: No am end the TAG, sorry it's copy-paste mistake . Still Same Error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was Fragment Context is not found properly.

> There are the some change on Map.java class

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static MapsActivity newInstance() {
        MapsActivity fragment = new MapsActivity();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```